SUMA TOTAL, UTILIZANDO LOOKUP REPORTING SERVICES
estoy realizando un reporte en Reporting Services pero tengo problemas con la estructura de la expresion para un campo en donde necesito obtener el total de ese campo.
Para sacar el valor de los lotes, utilizo esta expresion
=Sum(Fields!ORDER_QUANTITY.Value)/Lookup(Fields!COMPANY_CODE.Value+Fields!PART_CODE.Value,
Fields!COMPANY_CODE.Value+Fields!PRINCIPAL_PRODUCT.Value,Fields!PROCESS_PLANNING_BATCH_QTY.Value,"lotes")
Pero ahora necesito sacar el total, para que pueda cuadrarme el reporte sucesivamente. En este caso el numero de orden, solo tiene una linea en el detalle y el resultado del lote es 34.37, en teoría donde quiero realizar la expresión del total, debería de darme lo mismos 34.37 porque no existen más lotes.
que es lo que esta marcado con azul en la imagen.

